# Префаб в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Есть префаб на котором висит скрипт. Для работы скрипта необходимо два текстовых элемента. Если я их туда помещаю, а потом создаю экземпляр префаба, то текстовые объекты оттуда пропадают. Как сделать, чтобы при создании префаба текстовые объекты сохранялись в его экземплярах или какую функцию вставить в скрипт чтобы он автоматически брал данные объекты?

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Answer (score 0):

сохрани изменения в префабе нажав "apply" на втором скриншоте.